# Permission Denied Mac Big Sur - Installing Rails & Zsh

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, permissions, macos-big-sur

Probably a noob question but I have scoured everywhere and tried everything I can find but I can't seem to adjust permissions on my Mac. Whenever I try to install via the terminal I get permission denied.

`******@McKays-MacBook-Pro ~ % gem install rails -v 6.1.1                   ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES) Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /Users/mckayanhder/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/mimemagic-0.3.10/.gitignore ******@McKays-MacBook-Pro ~ %`

I am the admin, I've tried using chmod, chown, and sudo when trying to force permissions. I've also run first aid on the utility disk permissions which did take a while but still no luck.

Open to all suggestions/burns, just need to get this sorted.

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately I still get an invalid file mode for r+w